# recommendation for a long running query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We have a simple query that is running for ever. I can say more than 10 hours. Fact table has more than 17 billion rows. Any recommendations or best practices on improving following query performance?

```
SELECT
  /*+ parallel(f 4) */
  F.DM_CUSTOMER_DKEY,
  P.PRODUCT_YEAR,
  SUM(F.ADVG_COST_ACTUALS) advg_cost_actuals
FROM DM_CUST_RENEWAL_ADV_FACT F
INNER JOIN DM_PRODUCT_HIERARCHY p
ON F.DM_PRODUCT_HKEY = P.DM_PRODUCT_HKEY
GROUP BY F.DM_CUSTOMER_DKEY,
  P.PRODUCT_YEAR
ORDER BY P.PRODUCT_YEAR
```

Here is the plan

```
OPERATION OBJECT_NAME OPTIONS COST PARTITION_START PARTITION_STOP
SELECT STATEMENT 10931402
PX COORDINATOR
PX SEND :TQ10005 QC (ORDER) 10931402
SORT ORDER BY 10931402
PX RECEIVE 10931402
PX SEND :TQ10004 RANGE 10931402
SORT GROUP BY 10931402
PX RECEIVE 10931402
PX SEND :TQ10003 HASH 10931402
SORT GROUP BY 10931402
HASH JOIN 1964410
Access Predicates
F.DM_PRODUCT_HKEY=P.DM_PRODUCT_HKEY
PX RECEIVE 335
PX SEND :TQ10002 BROADCAST 335
VIEW index$_join$_002 335
HASH JOIN BUFFERED
Access Predicates
ROWID=ROWID
PX RECEIVE 136
PX SEND :TQ10000 HASH 136
PX
BLOCK
ITERATOR 136
INDEX DM_PRODUCT_HIERARCHY_PK FAST FULL
SCAN
136
PX RECEIVE 280
PX SEND :TQ10001 HASH 280
PX
BLOCK
ITERATOR 280
INDEX DM_PRODUCT_HIERARCHY_LPK FAST FULL
SCAN
280
PX BLOCK ITERATOR 1878718 1 369
TABLE ACCESS DM_CUST_RENEWAL_ADV_FACT FULL 1878718 1 369
```

Comment: Sadly it is not that easy: Posting a query is not enough info to help you.

Comment: execution plan?  is there an index on DM_CUST_RENEWAL_ADV_FACT. DM_PRODUCT_HKEY?

Comment: Well, you could start by thinking on adding a filter to your query. Or fo you really need to sum those values for your whole fact table? (if that is the case, you should think of an OLAP solution for this)

Comment: Hello Juergen, Are you looking for certain things?

Comment: Is this a one-off query? If not you might want to consider a fast-refresh materialised view (which might be what Lamak is referring to); that doesn't help you for the initial creation but would mean you only suffered the pain once?

Comment: Try/check the following 3 indexes: 
Indexes on DM_CUST_RENEWAL_ADV_FACT:

 (1) F.DM_CUSTOMER_DKEY, F.DM_PRODUCT_HKEY, F.ADVG_COST_ACTUALS

Indexes on DM_PRODUCT_HIERARCHY:

 (1) P.DM_PRODUCT_HKEY, P.PRODUCT_YEAR
 (2) P.PRODUCT_YEAR

Comment: Any partition recommendations?

Comment: Forget indexes, unless you're looking for covering indexes. This looks like it should use a hash join. How many rows in the dimension table? What's the average row width of the fact table? Execution plan?

Comment: -1 Voting to close.  You have already asked this question.  At a minimum, you must post the full execution plan if you want to get meaningful help.  4 people have asked you for this now, why are you not posting it?

Comment: If you have a very large set of dimension data, such that all the values of DM_PRODUCT_HKEY and PRODUCT_YEAR exceed the amount of memory that can be allocated in the PGA for this query (so probably hundreds of MB) then hash partitioning the two tables on the value of DM_PRODUCT_HKEY will lead to a more efficient partion-wise join, but it's premature to try that unless you know that the dimension table is so large.

Comment: I have 50,319 members in "DM_PRODUCT_HIERARCHY" table.

Answer (score 0):

As already been said, try to properly index your table.
What I suppose is to partition that table http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c12parti.htm

partition it either by F.DM_CUSTOMER_DKEY or P.PRODUCT_YEAR or both of them.
Or at least you can put where statement to shrink by product_year or so and run multiple queries

Comment: I don't see how indexing or partitioning are going to help here. Can you expand your answer to explain?

Comment: it will help if he tries it with where statement... then he can write function for that select

Comment: Well it *might* help, but that seems like an answer to a different question.

Comment: well, then to answer a question: to improve query performance without alternative approach, the only thing that will help is to buy better hardware

Comment: I like the materialised view that Alex mentioned -- that could be very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the table DM_PRODUCT_HIERARCHY is small enough to fit into memory while query execution. In that case, a hash join is preferable and you don't need an index. You can try the NO_INDEX hint maybe together with the USE_HASH hint.

You group the result by DM_CUSTOMER_DKEY of the very large fact table.
Partitioning the fact table by this attribute will most probably improve the performance significantly.

You should also consider to create an aggregated fact table. This can be part of the ETL process. Maybe a Materialized View will work. But I have very bad experience with large materialized views. Especially if there are lots of changes in the source table, you will run into limits of the underlying technology.

To get a feeling about the "best" runtime, you should measure the time for a full table scan on your fact table. Make sure, you count a column (COLUMN_X in the sample) which has no index, otherwise you will measure the time to scan the index instead of the table.

```
SELECT count(COLUMN_X) from DM_CUST_RENEWAL_ADV_FACT;
```